# Does hive have a data dictionary?

Tags: hadoop, hive, data-dictionary

Does hive have a data dictionary? 
I am trying to fetch the column names of tables in hive.
Similar to oracle query other than describe command:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME,DATA_TYPE FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = ? ORDER BY COLUMN_ID;
```

Answer (score 1):

Hive uses an external relational database as its [metastore](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AdminManual+MetastoreAdmin). You can query the configured metastore directly, using the metastore API (eg. MySQL). A higher level component is [HCatalog](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HCatalog), which offers an API to access and manipulate the metastore.

Answer (score 0):

Hive works in three configurations:

1. **Local:** In local configuration meta-store is stored in a relational database. But it runs in same JVM's.
2. **Remote:** In this configuration meta-store is stored in a relational database but database is located remote. And runs in a separate JVM.
3. **Embedded:** In embedded configuration meta store is a derby database. This database comes with Hive. And runs in the same jvm as Hive Services, Hive Client and Meta Store.This is called as embedded configuration.