# How do i get table count for all tables in the same folder in HADOOP hive? if in SAS server?

Tags: hadoop, hive, sas

I want to get the table count for all tables under a folder called "planning" in HADOOP hive database but i couldn't figure out a way to do so. Most of these tables are not inter-linkable and hence cant use full join with common key.

Is there a way to do table count and output to 1 table with each row of record represent 1 table name?

Table name that i have:
add_on
sales
ppu
ssu
car

Secondly, I am a SAS developer. Is the above process do-able in SAS? I tried data dictionary but "nobs" is totally blank for this library. All other SAS datasets can display "nobs" properly. I wonder why and how.

Comment: You can pull this from the hive data separately, can you run a pass through sql to hit the db directlY? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22472258/does-hive-have-a-data-dictionary